# Web service call through JS, DataType Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I am trying to call web service through a JS but anyhow it doesnt get call.
I am trying to make sum of 2 number.

Page contains of 3 `textbox` and it has it text set hard codded
as 
:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Text1"  Text="5" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="Text2" Text="2" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="Text3" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
```

My code are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "C:/Users/hp/Documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication3/WebApplication3/WebService1.asmx/sum",
                data: "{'a':'" + $('input[id$=Text1]').val() + "','b':'" + $('input[id$=Text2]').val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",


                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    var results = eval('(' + data.d + ')');
                    if (results == "success") {

                        $('input[id$=Text3]').val(data);
                        //$('span[id$=lblErr]').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('span[id$=lblmsg]').hide();

                        // $('span[id$=lblErr]').show();

                    }


                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                }


            });
        });

    </script>
```

WebService name WebForm1.aspx

```
 public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string sum(string a, string b)
        {
            string json = "";
            int sum = Convert.ToInt32(a) + Convert.ToInt32(b);
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            json = oSerializer.Serialize(sum);
            return json;


        }

    }
```

It showing Error box on each run. Kindly assist me through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your using a absolute URL to your webservice. You should be using a relative server path like this snippet suggests:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: "{ your: 'data' }",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "WebService1.asmx/sum",
   success: function (data) {
       alert(data); //use your data object
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong. It should be of this form:

```
 url: "/WebService1.asmx/sum"
```

And to make sure it always resolves to the right path, you can instead do this:

```
url: '<%=ResolveClientURL("~/WebService1.asmx/sum%>")'
```

Also, in your success handler, you don't need to do:

```
 var results = eval('(' + data.d + ')');
```

You can simply do:

```
var result= data.d;
```

Finally, in your WebMethod, you don't need to use the JavascriptSerializer at all. You can simply do:

```
 int sum = ...  
 return sum;
```

The response is already in JSON format. No need to serialize it twice.

Comment: sir i have tried both your URL but the path doesn't resolved to Absolute.

Comment: @Abhishek it should resolve to the Relative Path, not the Absolute path. You don't want the absolute.

Comment: Is the WebService hit at all?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> url: "C:/Users/hp/Documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication3/WebApplication3/WebService1.asmx/sum",
> ```

This needs to be an HTTP URL, and the HTML document that the JavaScript is running in needs to be on [the same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

> ```
> data: "{'a':'" + $('input[id$=Text1]').val() + "','b':'" + $('input[id$=Text2]').val() + "'}",
> ```

Your JSON is invalid. Strings must be delimited with `"` characters, not `'`, and user input could break it easily.

Do not generate JSON by mashing strings together. Use the built-in functions which will do it for you, correctly.

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    a: $('input[id$=Text1]').val(),
    b: $('input[id$=Text2]').val()
}),
```